# How do I query the bitfinex API every second?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, http, cron

I am trying to connect to Bitfinex's public api and get data every second from there.

I thought of as a cron job but I do not know whether it is possible to send a request every 1 second with for instance, whenever gem or sidekiq.

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

data = []
url = URI('https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd')

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)

r = JSON.parse(response.body)

data << {bid: r["bid"], ask: r["ask"], last: r["last_price"], low: r["low"], high: r["high"], volume: r["volume"], timestamp: Time.now.utc.to_f, name: exchange_name, error: false}
```

That works as expected, but as I mentioned, I would like to run this function every second.

PS: Also if this http request fail then it should rescue somehow.

Comment: You will certainly be rate limited at that frequency, no?

Answer (score -1):

You should use active worker instead of a cronjob, that way you get better built in support and the task is not dependant on server configuration but on the code

Reference guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html